# Force batchfile to fail in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, return-value

I have a windows batchfile run by Jenkins that check a file,
in case that the responce is fail the batchfile must return an error code.

I've tryed to do it in the following way:

```
findstr /m /c:"FAIL" testJenkins.log
if not errorlevel 1 (
    EXIT /B 1
    echo main batch  FAIL >>testJenkins.log 
) else (
 findstr /m /c:"SKIP" testJenkins.log
 if not errorlevel 1 (
     EXIT /B 1
     echo main batch  SKIP >>testJenkins.log 
 ) else (
     EXIT /B 0 
   echo main batch  PASS >>testJenkins.log 
 )
)
```

but the result of the Jenkins job is always green.

Comment: are you sure that `testJenkins.log` contains "FAIL" or "SKIP"?

Answer (score 3):

Your `EXIT` commands prevent `echo` lines to execute. First, `echo` what you need, then `exit`